# Rolling an $n$-sided die until repeat is found

Tags: probability-theory

Problem: We are rolling an $n$-sided die. You roll until you reach a number which you have rolled previously. I need to calculate the probability $p_m$ that we have rolled $m$ times for such a repeat.

My first thought was to try some inputs. I took $n=6$. I noticed that when $m=1$, we will always get a probability of $0$, since you are only rolling one time. Also, for $m>7$, we will also have $0$, since we will never reach that case. Now, I don't get how to find a general formula for when $1<m<8$

Comment: Is the die balanced?  I.e., are all the $n$ scores equiprobable?

Comment: Hint: what is the probability to not roll the first number on the second throw?You can roll n-1 numbers so it is $\frac{n-1}{n}$ Now see fo the third throw and think about the pattern.

Comment: Don't worry about a general formula at first. Can you find $p_2$? What about $p_3$? etc.

Answer (score 3):

The probability of not finishing in $k$ rolls is
$$
\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{n^k}=\frac{k!}{n^k}\binom{n}{k}\tag{1}
$$
Thus, $p_k$, the probability of finishing on the $k^{\text{th}}$ roll is
$$
\frac{(k-1)!}{n^{k-1}}\binom{n}{k-1}-\frac{k!}{n^k}\binom{n}{k}
=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{(k-1)!}{n^{k-1}}\binom{n-1}{k-2}}\tag{2}
$$
Another way to compute $p_k$ is the probability of not finishing in $k-1$ rolls times the probability of finishing in $k$ rolls given that we have not finished in $k-1$ rolls, which is $\frac{k-1}n$:
$$
\frac{(k-1)!}{n^{k-1}}\binom{n}{k-1}\frac{k-1}n
=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{(k-1)!}{n^{k-1}}\binom{n-1}{k-2}}\tag{3}
$$
Using $(2)$ or $(3)$, we can compute the expected number of rolls until a repeat is achieved is
$$
\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{k!}{n^{k-1}}\binom{n-1}{k-2}\tag{4}
$$
For $n=6$, $(4)$ gives the expected number of rolls to be
$$
\frac{1223}{324}\doteq3.774691358\tag{5}
$$

---

Asymptotically, $(4)$ can be approximated by
$$
\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{k!}{n^{k-1}}\binom{n-1}{k-2}\sim\sqrt{\frac{n\pi}2}+\frac23\tag{6}
$$
with an error of approximately $\frac1{10\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: +1. It would be interesting to find a closed form of $\left(\, 4\,\right)$. Is it possible ?. Thanks.

Comment: @FelixMarin: it would.  I have not found one yet, but I have been trying.

Comment: @FelixMarin: I have not found a closed form, so I have given an asymptotic approximation.

Comment: Thanks. I'll think about it. It looks hard. Maybe, Stirling Numbers...

Answer (score 1):

for a die with $n$ sides, if you haven't already seen a duplicate, the probability of getting a repeat on the $k$th roll is

$$\frac{k-1}{n}$$

So, to get a repeat exactly on the $j$ you must first succeed at getting to the $j$th roll without any repeats, and then roll a repeat:

$$\begin{align}P(j) &= \frac{j-1}{n}\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{j-1}\left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\\
&=\frac{j-1}{n}\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{j-1}\left(\frac{n+1-k}{n}\right)\\
&=\frac{j-1}{n^j}\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{j-1}\left(n+1-k\right)\\
&=\frac{j-1}{n^j}\cdot\left(n\times(n-1)\times\cdots\times(n+3-j)\times(n+2-j)\right)\\
&=\frac{j-1}{n^j}\cdot\frac{n!}{(n+1-j)!}\\
&=\frac{n!\cdot(j-1)}{(n+1-j)!\cdot n^j}\end{align}$$

Comment: Or, in what I think is slightly more elegant:  $\frac{(n-1)!\cdot(j-1)}{(n-(j-1))\cdot n^{j-1}}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If you rolled $m$ times, that means the first $m-1$ must all have been different results, and the $m$th roll is one of the first $m-1$.

For example, if $m=3$, that means the first two rolls must be distinct, and then the third roll must match one of the first two. So this is $\frac{6}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{2}{6}$. (There is a $5/6$ chance that the second roll does not match the first. There is a $2/6$ chance that the third roll matches one of the first two).

> In general, $\frac{\frac{6!}{(7-m)!} \cdot (m-1)}{6^m}$.

Comment: How did you come to that general formula, can you put how you derived it?

Comment: @user23899 Perhaps just do the computation for $p_2,p_3,\ldots,p_7$ and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

the first roll does not matter, the second roll, since you dont want it to have the same number as the first, then the prob is $\frac{n-1}{n}$, so does for the third, forth, and so on until the $(m-1)$th roll. And for the last, because you want it to have same number, the probability is $\frac{1}{n}$. Hence, the answer is $\frac{(n-1)^{m-2}}{n^{m-1}}$.

Comment: Wouldn't the third roll have to avoid *two* values?

Comment: I think you have interpreted "repeat" as two consecutive rolls being the same. If you read OP's post, you'll see "repeat" means matching a previous roll.

Comment: ah i see, so I did misunderstand the question, then the solution by Dan Uznanski is right in my opinion